# Unable to access a couple web sites

Tags: http, timeout, web

I am unable to access a couple web sites which I built and have hosted @ dailyrazor.com.  Their technical support folks tell me the problem is with my ISP, Charter.  I call Charter and they ping my modem and tell me there is no problem!  I have tried turning off firewall, virus software, and attempted using three different browsers.  I can access these sites from my Android phone just fine.  Can anyone tell me what I could look at next?

Comment: did charter ping the domains you can't access?

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging the host name of the site.  This will tell you if your DNS setup is resolving the hostname to an IP address correctly.

Comment: The ping times out as does tracert.  One of the sites is droidwill.com, and the folks at DailyRazor (hosting provider) asked me to try this http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://droidwill.com.  Surprisingly, hitting this link DOES get me to the site

Comment: @stanlick: The important thing with ping is that the hostname resolves to a valid, routable IP address.  If you're getting that then okay.  Pings timing out doesn't necessarily mean much.  Are you going through a proxy server?

Comment: C:\Users\scott>ping droidwill.com

Pinging droidwill.com [199.85.212.225] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 199.85.212.225:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\scott>

Comment: @stanlick: It resolves to the same IP for me, but my pings get through.  How far does tracert get?